# PySpark - Select users seen for 3 days a week for 3 weeks a month

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know this is a very specific problem and it is not usual to post this kind of question on stackoverflow, but I am in the strange situation of having an idea of a naive algorithm that would solve my issue, but not being able to implement it. Hence my question.

I have a data frame

```
|user_id| action | day | week |
------------------------------
| d25as | AB     | 2   | 1    |
| d25as | AB     | 3   | 2    |
| d25as | AB     | 5   | 1    | 
| m3562 | AB     | 1   | 3    |
| m3562 | AB     | 7   | 1    |
| m3562 | AB     | 9   | 1    |
| ha42a | AB     | 3   | 2    |
| ha42a | AB     | 4   | 3    |
| ha42a | AB     | 5   | 1    |
```

I want to create a dataframe with users that are seem **at least 3 days a week** for **at least 3 weeks a month**. The "day" column goes from 1 to 31 and the "week" column goes from 1 to 4.

The way I thought about doing it is :

```
split dataframe into 4 dataframes for each week
for every week_dataframe count days seen per user. 
count for every user how many weeks with >= 3 days they were seen.
only add to the new df the users seen for >= 3 such weeks.
```

Now I need to do this in Spark and in a way that scales and I have no idea how to implement it. Also ,if you have a better idea of an algorithm than my naive approach, that would really be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using groupBy function with selecting users with where selector:

```
df.groupBy('user_id', 'week')\
.agg(countDistinct('day').alias('days_per_week'))\
.where('days_per_week >= 3')\
.groupBy('user_id')\
.agg(count('week').alias('weeks_per_user'))\
.where('weeks_per_user >= 3' )
```

Comment: I get a : AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'countDistinct'

Comment: sorry, I forgot 'agg' function around 'countDistinct'. Check edited version.

Answer (score 1):

@eakotelnikov is correct.

But if anyone is facing the error

> NameError: name 'countDistinct' is not defined

then please use below statement prior to execute eakotelnikov solution

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

Adding another solution for this problem

```
tdf.registerTempTable("tbl")

outdf = spark.sql(""" 
select user_id , count(*) as weeks_per_user from
( select user_id , week , count(*) as days_per_week 
  from tbl 
  group by user_id , week  
  having count(*) >= 3
 ) x
group by user_id
having count(*) >= 3
""")

outdf.show()
```